# Recipe for target failed (Qt Creator)

Tags: qt, mingw, qt-creator

I have Hello World app that consists mainwindow.h, mainwindow.cpp, main.cpp and also mainwindow.ui. When I try to compile it, I receive following error messages:

```
    E:\Qt\5.2.1\msvc2012_64_opengl\bin\uic.exe mainwindow.ui -o ui_mainwindow.h
    Makefile.Debug:226: recipe for target 'ui_mainwindow.h' failed
    mingw32-make[1]: *** [ui_mainwindow.h] Error -1073741515
    mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'E:/Qt/workspace/Run'
    Makefile:34: recipe for target 'debug' failed
    mingw32-make: *** [debug] Error 2.
```

So I suppose ui_mainwindow.h is generated, but compiler can't find it at next step.
How can fix it?

Comment: Error -1073741515 looks Like a Windows error code. Google it. Also convert to hex and google with that. There's some problem with `uic`, it seems.

Comment: Can't find anything with error codes. Maybe I should try to install another version of Creator

Comment: Try t delete all all files in build directory including make files and rebuild your project.

Comment: Solved the problem by installing Qt for MinGW.

Answer (score 0):

The same problem was fixed (http://www.prog.org.ru/topic_27434_0.html). It seems no ICU DLLs in your bin dir.
(Change pathes for yours).

> copy C:\icu\bin*.dll C:\Qt\Qt5.7.0n\bin\